# Better way to skip comments in a file parsing

Tags: regex, parsing, groovy

At the moment I use

```
<file>.eachLine { line ->
    if (line ==~ /^#.*$/) {
        return // skip comments
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way?

Comment: you mean like `if (line.startsWith('#')) { // do processing`...  Not sure what you're after?

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that one. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to separate the test for comments from the rest of the code in your closure?
You could do this, for some File 'f'....

```
f.filterLine( { it ==~ /^[^#].*/ } ).each { < process non-comments > }
```